# The Wonderful Wanderfull Puzz

Tags: word, rhyme, wordplay

In the land of Puzz, all the days are strange
The sounds repeat, but with one wee change
A troll trail hither and a dwarf wharf yon
A wee hairy fairy or a fat fun faun

Won't you come walking through the land with me
And fill in all the blanks with the things we'll see
Then take the circled letters as a brand new clue
Solve that final riddle; there's some rep for you

First we see a werewolf with a tongue so neat
That he uses it to sample all the foods he'll eat
If you're a tasty morsel, better not go hikin'
Or you might get eaten by a hungry `_ (_) _ _ _ _'   _ _ _ _ _`

Notice the ravine as we follow this wall
For that deep `_ _ _ _ _   (_) _ _ _ _` is where green hags fall
And best avoid the clearing where the green oaf mills
For his giant `(_) _ _ _   _ _ _ _ (_)` is the greatest of drills

Now behold a beast in the western sky
It's furry and it's feathered and it loves to fly
But its favourite thing of all is a function plot
Lo, it's a `_ _ (_) _ _ _ _'  _ _ _ _ _ _ (_)` that your eye doth spot

Now over in that hut are a wee green few
They're called the `_ _ (_) _ _ _ _'   (_) _ _ _ _ _ _` and they all make shoes
And the many goaty fellows in the field ahead
Are the sexy `_ (_) _ _ _   _ _ _ _ _ _ _` that are fit to wed

Behold the next beast on the eastern flat
A little bit of this and a little bit of that
But all three parts think pictures are a hoot
The `_ _ _ _ (_) _   _ _ _ _ _ _ _` has some photos to shoot

That ugly furry fellow on his brown hind legs?
He's a `_ _ _ _ _   (_) _ _ _ _`, but his humour is the dregs
And the faint white spirit there never plays the host
Whenever she's invited, she's a true `(_) _ _ _ _   _ _ _ _ _`.

As we wind down, mind that tree-like fellow
He's got a nasty bark though he may seem mellow
His father has a sister and she's really quite rude
Blame his `_ _ _   _ _ (_) _` for the old sot's mood

That concludes our tour through the land of Puzz
But all tours have a purpose, just as this one does
List the circled letters and then rearrange the list
**To name the boastful fellow on the tour we missed**
*Please include answers to the ten clues with your solution.*

Comment: Do the apostrophes in the blanked-out parts correspond to actual apostrophes? What about the spaces between words?

Comment: @randal'thor: Yes, the apostrophes correspond to actual apostrophes. And the spaces between words correspond to spaces. For example `_ _ _ _ _ _'   _ _ _ _ _ _` could be `HITTIN' KITTEN` or `KICKIN' KITTEN`.

Comment: @COTO: The example you chose worries me...

Comment: @Deusovi: `CUTTIN' KITTEN` and `SITTIN' KITTEN` work too. ;)

Comment: @COTO Not much improvement there.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In the land of Puzz, all the days are strange
The sounds repeat, but with one wee change
A troll trail hither and a dwarf wharf yon
A wee hairy fairy or a fat fun faun

> This stanza tells us that the theme of the puzzle is two-word phrases where each word is just one sound away from the other, such as **dwarf wharf.**

Won't you come walking through the land with me
And fill in all the blanks with the things we'll see
Then take the circled letters as a brand new clue
Solve that final riddle; there's some rep for you

> So let's begin solving!

First we see a werewolf with a tongue so neat
That he uses it to sample all the foods he'll eat
If you're a tasty morsel, better not go hikin'
Or you might get eaten by a hungry `_ (_) _ _ _ _'   _ _ _ _ _`

> L(I)CKIN' LYCAN

Notice the ravine as we follow this wall
For that deep `_ _ _ _ _   (_) _ _ _ _` is where green hags fall
And best avoid the clearing where the green oaf mills
For his giant `(_) _ _ _   _ _ _ _ (_)` is the greatest of drills

> WITCH (D)ITCH
>  (O)GRE AUGE(R)

Now behold a beast in the western sky
It's furry and it's feathered and it loves to fly
But its favourite thing of all is a function plot
Lo, it's a `_ _ (_) _ _ _ _'  _ _ _ _ _ _ (_)` that your eye doth spot

> GR(A)PHIN' GRIFFIN

Now over in that hut are a wee green few
They're called the `_ _ (_) _ _ _ _'   (_) _ _ _ _ _ _` and they all make shoes
And the many goaty fellows in the field ahead
Are the sexy `_ (_) _ _ _   _ _ _ _ _ _ _` that are fit to wed

> CO(B)BLIN' (G)OBLINS
>  S(A)TYR SUITORS

Behold the next beast on the eastern flat
A little bit of this and a little bit of that
But all three parts think pictures are a hoot
The `_ _ _ _ (_) _   _ _ _ _ _ _ _` has some photos to shoot

> CAME(R)A CHIMERA

That ugly furry fellow on his brown hind legs?
He's a `_ _ _ _ _   (_) _ _ _ _`, but his humour is the dregs
And the faint white spirit there never plays the host
Whenever she's invited, she's a true `(_) _ _ _ _   _ _ _ _ _`.

> DROLL (G)NOLL
>  (G)UEST GHOST

As we wind down, mind that tree-like fellow
He's got a nasty bark though he may seem mellow
His father has a sister and she's really quite rude
Blame his `_ _ _   _ _ (_) _` for the old sot's mood

> ENT AU(N)T

That concludes our tour through the land of Puzz
But all tours have a purpose, just as this one does
List the circled letters and then rearrange the list
**To name the boastful fellow on the tour we missed**

> Finally, we're left with IDORANBGARGGN, which anagrams to BRAGGIN' DRAGON.

Comment: Oh, nice! This is much better and more complete than my answer. How about (GLOOM?) GNOME for the one clue you didn't get?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out why @COTO specifies "ugly" and "hind legs"...

Comment: All correct except for that one clue. A hint: the creature we're looking for is mythical. It's nearly always depicted as an humanoid hyena walking on its hind legs. The adjective in front of its name is a synonym for "funny".

Comment: @COTO, I think I got it! I gotta say, this may very well be my favorite puzzle on the site. I love it and would upvote it a billion times if I could!

Answer (score 2):

### Partial answer

First we see a werewolf with a tongue so neat
That he uses it to sample all the foods he'll eat
If you're a tasty morsel, better not go hikin'
Or you might get eaten by a hungry `_ (_) _ _ _ _'   _ _ _ _ _`

> I think this is a VIKING, since it needs to rhyme with hiking. Not quite sure on the two words though, since the first is 6 letters with an apostrophe and the second is 5 letters with no apostrophe.

Notice the ravine as we follow this wall
For that deep `_ _ _ _ _   (_) _ _ _ _` is where green hags fall
And best avoid the clearing where the green oaf mills
For his giant `(_) _ _ _   _ _ _ _ (_)` is the greatest of drills

> Not sure about either of these clues.

Now behold a beast in the western sky
It's furry and it's feathered and it loves to fly
But its favourite thing of all is a function plot
Lo, it's a `_ _ (_) _ _ _ _'  _ _ _ _ _ _ (_)` that your eye doth spot

> I think this is a GRIFFIN/GRYPHON (it has fur, feathers, wings, and in at least one fictional work they're often mathematicians). So the two words could be "spiffin' griffin", making the letters **IN**.

Now over in that hut are a wee green few
They're called the `_ _ (_) _ _ _ _'   (_) _ _ _ _ _ _` and they all make shoes

> LEPRECHAUNS are green and said to make shoes. But there must be another name for them, since neither of those words are 10-11 letters long.

And the many goaty fellows in the field ahead
Are the sexy `_ (_) _ _ _   _ _ _ _ _ _ _` that are fit to wed

> SATYRS are half-goat and supposedly sexy. So maybe the first word is "satyr", which means the missing letter is **A**.

Behold the next beast on the eastern flat
A little bit of this and a little bit of that
But all three parts think pictures are a hoot
The `_ _ _ _ (_) _   _ _ _ _ _ _ _` has some photos to shoot

> This could be a CHIMERA/CHIMAERA, which has parts of three different animals (although I'm not sure about the photos bit), so the second word is "chimera" but I'm not sure about the first.

That ugly furry fellow on his brown hind legs?
He's a `_ _ _ _ _   (_) _ _ _ _`, but his humour is the dregs

> Not sure about this one.

And the faint white spirit there never plays the host
Whenever she's invited, she's a true `(_) _ _ _ _   _ _ _ _ _`.

> This is surely a GHOST (faint white spirit, rhymes with host), so the second word is "ghost" but I'm not sure about the first.

As we wind down, mind that tree-like fellow
He's got a nasty bark though he may seem mellow
His father has a sister and she's really quite rude
Blame his `_ _ _   _ _ (_) _` for the old sot's mood

> Could be a TROLL, but neither of the words have 5 letters. An ENT maybe?

Letters gathered so far:

> INA.